# How to replicate nested from statement to nested with statement?

Tags: sql, nested, with-statement

I have created a nested from statement that can be seen below:

```
SELECT Player.playerid, name as [Full Name], avgs as [Player Average], format(teamavg, 'C') as [Team Average],Player.teamid, format((Team.teamavg - Player.avgs), 'C') AS [Difference], yr as [Last Year]
        FROM (SELECT playerid, teamid, MAX(yearid) as yr, format(avg(salary), 'c') AS avgs
                     FROM Spring_2021_BaseBall.dbo.Salaries 
                     GROUP BY playerID, teamid) Player,
        (SELECT teamid, yearid, avg(salary) AS teamavg
                FROM Spring_2021_BaseBall.dbo.Salaries 
                GROUP BY teamid, yearid) Team,
        (SELECT playerid,
                CONCAT(nameGiven, ' (', nameFirst, ')', ' ', nameLast) as name 
                FROM Spring_2021_BaseBall.dbo.People ) Name
      WHERE Player.playerid = Name.playerid and 
            Player.teamid = Team.teamid and 
            Player.yr= Team.yearid
      ORDER BY Player.playerid ASC, yearid DESC
```

I am trying to recreate the same results with a nested with statement, I have attempted the below, but it results in a multi-part identifier could not be bound. How would I solve this issue because I thought I named each query correctly?

```
With Player (playerid, teamid, yearid, avgs)  as (SELECT playerid, teamid, MAX(yearid), format(avg(salary), 'C') as avgs 
         FROM Spring_2021_BaseBall.dbo.Salaries 
         GROUP BY playerid, teamid), 
     Team (teamid, yearid, teamavg) as (SELECT teamid, yearid, avg(salary) as teamavg
         FROM Spring_2021_BaseBall.dbo.Salaries 
         GROUP BY teamid, yearid), 
     FullName (playerid, name) as (SELECT playerid, CONCAT(nameGiven, ' (', nameFirst, ')', ' ', nameLast) as name 
         FROM Spring_2021_BaseBall.dbo.People)
Select Player.playerid, Player.teamid, Player.yearid, Player.avgs, Team.teamavg, FullName.name 
         FROM Spring_2021_BaseBall.dbo.Salaries, Spring_2021_BaseBall.dbo.People
         WHERE Player.playerid = FullName.playerid and 
            Player.teamid = Team.teamid and 
            Player.yr= Team.yearid
         ORDER BY Player.playerid ASC, yearid DESC
go
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last `FROM` statement is still referring to the original tables, not the ones that are defined with the `WITH` statement.

If you change it from

```
FROM Spring_2021_BaseBall.dbo.Salaries, Spring_2021_BaseBall.dbo.People
```

to

```
FROM Player, Team, FullName
```

should give you the expected result